# python tuple over writing previous data

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, tuples

I am trying to create a function that will start the loop and add a day to current day count, it will ask 3 questions then combine that data to equal Total_Output. I then want 'n' to represent the end of the tuple, and in the next step add the Total_Output to the end of the tuple. But when I run the function it seems like it is creating a new tuple.

Example:

```
Good Morninghi
This is Day: 1
How much weight did you use?40
How many reps did you do?20
How many sets did you do?6
Day: 1
[4800.0]
This is Day: 2
How much weight did you use?50
How many reps did you do?20
How many sets did you do?6
Day: 2
[6000.0, 6000.0]
This is Day: 3
How much weight did you use?40
How many reps did you do?20
How many sets did you do?6
Day: 3
[4800.0, 4800.0, 4800.0]
failed
```

Here is the function:

```
def Start_Work(x):
    Num_Days = 0
    Total_Output = 0
    Wght = 0
    Reps = 0
    Sets = 0
    Day = []

    while x == 1 and Num_Days < 6: ##will be doing in cycles of 6 days
        Num_Days += 1     ##increase day count with each loop
        print "This is Day:",Num_Days
        Wght = float(raw_input("How much weight did you use?"))
        Reps = float(raw_input("How many reps did you do?"))
        Sets = float(raw_input("How many sets did you do?"))
        Total_Output = Wght * Reps * Sets
        n = Day[:-1]   ##go to end of tuple
        Day = [Total_Output for n in range(Num_Days)] ##add data (Total_Output to end of tuple
        print "Day:",Num_Days  
        print Day
    else:
        print "failed"

Input = raw_input("Good Morning")
if Input.lower() == str('hi') or str('start') or str('good morning'):
  Start_Work(1)
else:
    print "Good Bye"
```

Comment: BTW, what's up with `Title_Case_With_Underscores`? Also `'start'` is already a `str`, no need to convert it to one. Also what's up with `while x == 1`? Where is this `x` from? Also, look up the `xrange` builtin.

Comment: this is part a larger program, and i plan on doing these in days, weeks and months so I wanted to make the Function names very unique. The 'x' is because in the larger program it will be asking for an exercises... ie: "benches,crunches,squats" where benches = 1, crunches = 2 and squats = 3. And that would be where the value of 'x' will change. Each of the exercises will have loops outside of this that will require increased out put by either weight or reps or sets. and i was actually meaning to clean out the 'start' part because it was from when I had previously tried to write this.

Comment: Oh, and the start part is because i thought i had to declare the type to force it to be lower, gonna try to do it with out the 'str' and save myself some keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n = Day[:-1]   ##go to end of tuple
Day = [Total_Output for n in range(Num_Days)] ##add data (Total_Output to end of tuple
```

Does not do what you think it does. You assign `n` but never use it (the `n` in the loop is assigned by the `for n in`), and it only hold a `list` of the end of the `Day` variable.

You then set `Day` to be `[Total_Output] * Num_Days`, so you make a new `list` of `Num_Days` occurrences of `Total_Output`.

You want:

```
Day.append(Total_Output)
```

to replace both of those lines.

Comment: WOW, thank you, now that I am looking at that I dont understand how i didnt think of that. It works exactly how I wanted it to now, awesome .... and now I have a bunch of code to rewrite lol, Thanks again